# "人物" vs. "性格" vs. "人柄"?

Tags: word-choice

With regard to talking about one's "*personality*", such as one being out-going, stoic, cold, not trustworthy, etc. I've always said "**人柄{ひとがら}**". And, the natives seem to basically understand what I mean.

1. With regard to how it sounds, are "**性格{せいかく}**" and "**人物{じんぶつ}**" both really formal to use in a conversation?
2. What are a few contexts where "人柄" is not understandable / very inappropriate, and "性格" and/or "人物" must be used?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**性格**

The bottom line of this word is "temperament", "disposition". And this one is **the most common word** to describe a person's personality. It translates "character" in psychological terms, and also used for a thing's characteristics.

**人柄**

A word mostly for one's interpersonal character. But effectively, it's almost always used to tell what kind of **virtue** whoever has, thus **not much compatible with bad evaluation**. For example, 人柄が冷たい (="has cold character"?) only had [7 hits in Google.jp](https://www.google.co.jp/search?hl=ja&q=%22%E4%BA%BA%E6%9F%84%E3%81%8C%E5%86%B7%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%22). We could say 人柄が良くない, but 人柄が悪い sounds a little stiff if not wrong.

**人物**

This one is more like *person* (respectable figure, someone important) or *identity*, rather than *personality*. But it can be used as a more formal alternative to 人柄, as well. On this point the usage is similar to 人柄. The word also translates "character" in drama, so 悪い人物 is likely to be *baddie*.

---

**BONUS**

**人格{じんかく}**: persona, "personality" in psychology as in 多重人格 "multiple personality".

**個性{こせい}**: personality, individuality; but since Japanese culture doesn't praise being special, this word sometimes means "eccentricity".

**性向{せいこう}**: (behavioral) tendency, propensity.

**根性{こんじょう}**: (*old-fashioned and/or slangy*) habitualized attitude, innate or acquired. Also means "guts" or "patience" by its own.